# In NHibernate, can I use factory to build complex aggregate object (Entity)?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, domain-driven-design, factory

In NHibernate, can I use factory to build complex aggregate object (Entity)? 
If yes then how?
If not.. then what is your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you can make the object as a POCO, you can map in to your database with NHibernate.

However, you don't actually understand exactly what you need, so please post clearer requirements and I'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/04/17/Advance-Extending-NHibernate-Proxies.aspx) from Ayende where he describes creating a proxy factory to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on an entity proxy.